# path integral definition of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-field-theory

In the [functional determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant) page, for a self-adjoint operator on a finite-dimensional Euclidean space $V$, the formula holds
$${\frac  {1}{{\sqrt  {\det S}}}}=\int _{V}e^{{-\pi \langle x,Sx\rangle }}\,dx$$

Could anyone help me figure out why it holds? And what is the formula for ordinary matrix $S$?

Comment: Things can go wrong for $S$ that are not self-adjoint. For instance, if $S$ is a rotation matrix with angle $\theta$ then the integral is heuristically ${\rm vol}(V)\cdot e^{-\cos\theta}$ (which is obviously infinite). Or if $S$ has a negative eigenvalue with positive geometric multiplicity then my answer below gives a factor of $e^{+\lambda u^2}$ which also gives a divergent integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any symmetric matrix $A$ may be [decomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition) as $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is diagonal whose diagonal matrices are the (nonnegative) eigenvalues of $A$. Then

$$\int e^{-\langle x,Sx\rangle}dx=\int e^{-\langle x,Q\Lambda Q^Tx\rangle}dx=\int e^{-\langle Qu,Q\Lambda u\rangle}d(Qu) $$

using the substitution $u=Q^Tx$ with $du=dx$ since the Jacobian determinant is $\det Q$ (kind of absuing notation with $du$ and $dx$ supposed to be volume forms)

$$=\int e^{-\langle u,\Lambda u\rangle}du=\int e^{-(\lambda_1u_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_n u_n^2)}du_1\cdots du_n=\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda_i u_i^2}du_i. $$

With the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\pi}$ and substitution $v_i=\sqrt{\lambda_i}u_i$ this is

$$=\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v_i^2}d\frac{dv_i}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}=\frac{\big(\sqrt{\pi}\big)^n}{\sqrt{\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n}}=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\det A}} $$

which is $\propto (\det A)^{-1/2}$ ($\propto$ means "proportional to").

Comment: @artic tern Your explanation is very pedagogical. (A little remark : the eigenvalues should be  >0). Something that could be said is that there is a probabilistic interpretation of all this in terms of Multivariate Normal Distribution with matrix $Q$ being the **inverse** of the variance matrix see for example [this](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/lectures/MultivariateNormalDistribution-I.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie Mmhmm. And even if one or more of the eigenvalues is zero, the division by zero correctly predicts the integral's divergence.

Comment: I agree, but this must be said before using $\sqrt{det(A)}$ as a denominator.

Comment: Then if $S$ is not a constant matrix but a matrix function $S=S(x)$, we have ${\frac  {1}{{\sqrt  {\det S(x)}}}}=\int _{V}e^{{-\pi \langle y,S(x)y\rangle }}\,dy$. Can we obtain the formula for $\ln \det S(x)$ as $\ln \det S(x) = \int _{V}{{-\pi \langle y,S(x)y\rangle }}\,dy$?

Comment: $A=\int e^B$ does not imply $\ln A=\int B$ since $\ln$ is not additive!